# Rooting my samsung j7 gone wrong

Tags: rooting, samsung, 9.0-pie, samsung-galaxy-j7

I was rooting my android phone by following youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXyWgyW5-5M .
At step 2:11 [image]
after selecting bootloader only blue screen and downloading is written i.e. the above data is not written on my left top screen at the same time i started the odin and the odin log are

```
<ID:0/004> Added!!
<ID:0/004> Odin engine v(ID:3.1100)..
<ID:0/004> File analysis..
<ID:0/004> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/004> Initialzation..
<ID:0/004> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/004> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/004> SingleDownload.
<ID:0/004> boot.img
```

It is not proceeding after boot.img please help me and my phone keep on restarting continuously if i stop the process and turn on device normally.

Comment: seems you have done nothing wrong. to unbrick restore original unmodified boot.img (haven't watched video but i can imagine you tried to flash magisk patched boot.img and this probably causes boot loop)